# Java 8 break recursive loop

Tags: java, java-8

I have the following class which is a nested object,

```
public class Order implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

    // getters and setters   
}
```

Trying to find the matching order when I have complete list and order id,

```
private Order findMatchingOrder(String id, List <Order> orders, Order order) {
 for (Order o: orders) {
  if (o.getId().equals(id)) {
   order = o;
   break;
  } else {
   findMatchingOrder(id, o.getOrders(), o);
  }
 }
 return order;
}
```

Since it's a recursive call and even if I have a break in if condition, it executes the else block after executing break instead of coming out of for loop and returning the order.

Is there any other approach to achieve this? Preferably Java 8.

Comment: "*Is there any other approach to achieve this?*" - Yes: check what is returned. If something other than `null` has been returned by the recursive call, break the loop by returning what has been returned to you (you need to refactor your current algorithm to implement this approach).

Comment: I can't change my Order class though, the only thing I can change is this method. I was thinking since it's nested, can this be achieved using streams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attempting to pass the return value as an argument which doesn't work in this case. Instead I suggest you return the Order found and check for that result.

```
private Order findMatchingOrder(String id, List<Order> orders) {
    for (Order o: orders) {
        if (o.getId().equals(id)) 
            return o;

        Order found = findMatchingOrder(id, o.getOrders());
        if (found != null)
            return found;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Peter. This looks pretty good. Let me give it a try. Any idea if using streams makes sense here, and if it is doable at all?

Comment: @User0911 Streams can't be used to flatten a deep tree, which is what you have.

Comment: @User0911 it'snot easy to turn a recursive solution into one using a Stream.  You could use a custom Spliterator to navigate the tree but it would by more complicated.